# line break in report builder

Tags: printing, line, break, reportbuilder

I have to print a report in report builder with several items, but as the number of items increases they get impresos half on each page, I wonder if there is a way to line break in report builder.

Answer (score 0):

In an expression you can use the visual basic function [VBCRLF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx#VisualBasicFunctions).

```
="Line1 Text" + VBCRLF + "Line2 Text"
```